# EE Stash not passing to new page

Tags: stash, zoo-visitor

I’ve seen an example almost identical to what I’m trying to attempt here:
[How to get attempted url before access restriction?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9251/how-to-get-attempted-url-before-access-restriction)
However, my templates don’t see to want to cooperate:
Template 1:

```
    {if logged_in}
     {embed="myfig/upload-view"}
    {if:else}
     {exp:stash:set name="login_form_return" scope="user" save="yes"}{segment_2}    {/exp:stash:set}
    {redirect="/myfig/"}
    {/if}
```

Template 2:

```
Stash: {exp:stash:get name="login_form_return"}
```

{if '{exp:stash:get name="login_form_return"}'}
     Proof Manager
     {if:else}
     Something else
     {/if}

`{exp:zoo_visitor:login_form 
 error_handling="inline"
  }

 {if '{exp:stash:get name="login_form_return"}' =="myfig/proofmanager"}
 <input type="hidden" name="RET" value='myfig/proofmanager' />
 {if:else}
 <input type="hidden" name="RET" value="/myfig/dashboard/" />

 {/if}`

Nothing returns on my GET attempt. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This will most likely be to do with parse order. EE templates get processed in layers rather than top to bottom and you're using a complex conditional. To move it up the parse order try this:

```
{if logged_in}
    {embed="myfig/upload-view"}
{/if}
{if logged_out}
    {exp:stash:set name="login_form_return" scope="user" save="yes"}{segment_2}    {/exp:stash:set}
    {redirect="/myfig/"}
{/if}
```

This converts it to a simple conditional and may very well solve the issue.

Comment: Hi Ian - This didn't work. Any other thoughts?

Comment: The first thing to check would be that the conditionals are working correctly. Does `logged_out` work successfully if you remove the Stash tag and redirect and place a string ("I'm logged out") in there? Also just experiment with outputting the Stash variable within that conditional and remove the redirect. If you call `{exp:stash:login_form_return}` right after setting it does it display segment_2 correctly?

Comment: Glad that helped Jon. As it is the redirect then try setting `scope="site"` and keep `save="yes"` in there. Does that carry across to the page redirect?

Answer (score 0):

The redirects were killing the session. I had to try a different method of embedding a login form in the template I was in instead of redirecting